# Use Abbreviations in text without full meaning, even in First Use

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

I am using using the package `\usepackage{glossaries}` to insert abbreviations in my report, loaded from `myglossaries.tex` file, as below:

```
\usepackage[nopostdot,toc,acronym,nomain,nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\setacronymstyle{long-short}

\loadglsentries[acronym]{myglossaries}
```

And then define the abbreviations in `myglossaries.tex` as:

```
\newacronym[type=\glsdefaulttype]{svm}{SVM}{Support Vector Machine}
\newacronym[type=\glsdefaulttype]{gps}{GPS}{Global Positioning System}
\newacronym[type=\glsdefaulttype]{gis}{GIS}{Geographic Information System}
\newacronym[type=\glsdefaulttype]{dt}{DT}{Decision Tree}
\newacronym[type=\glsdefaulttype]{bn}{BN}{Beyesian Network}
\newacronym[type=\glsdefaulttype]{crf}{CRF}{Conditional Random Field}
```

Output OK:

[image]

**Queation:** How do I disable displaying full meaning of abbreviations at First Use, so for instance at first use of `\gls{gps}` in main text only `GPS` should appear not  `Global Positioning System(GPS)`. So that full meaning appears only in list of abbreviations.

To reproduce, I give the following example (First Use).

Code:

```
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ | m{1.5cm} | m{1.4cm}| m{1.5cm} | m{3.5cm}|m{1.5cm}| m{1.4cm} | m{1.2cm}| m{1.2cm}|}
    \hline
     Author(s) &  Modes Detected & Classifier & Features & Population & External Data &  Period & Accuracy \\
     \hline
     \cite{zheng2008understanding} & 4 & \gls{dt}, \gls{bn}, \gls{svm}, \gls{crf} & velocity \& acceleration (statistics) & 65 users [GeoLife] & No & 10 months & 76.1\%\\
     \hline
      \cite{zheng2008learning} & 4 & DT & distance, velocity \& acceleration statistics & 45 users [GeoLife] (check) & No & 6 months & 72.80\% \\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{A summary of previous studies.}
    \label{table01}
    \end{table}
```

Output:

[image]

Instead, I want it to look something like:

[image]

Comment: Please always provide an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) with your question. This helps people trying to help as well as others with similar problems and usually the process of creating a good MWE helps you as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use the [`glossaries-extra`](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra) package. Its default configuration is to use the style `short-nolong` for abbreviations created with `\newacronym` (as opposed to `\newabbreviation`). You can of course create your own abbreviation types or change the default ones if that distinction is insufficient for your needs. For details, see chapter 3 of the documentation.

Comment: Thank you, it does the job.